# Significance of compass heading values 4100-8200 in an old game?

Tags: gaming, algorithm

I'm developing a server for an old game client. The client sends the character's compass heading as a big-endian uint16 with a strange value. Due south is 4100. The value increases westward, approaching 8200 just east of south. The origin of the coordinate system is in the northwest corner.

Does the number 4100 ring a bell for anyone? Thinking about some of the clever stuff programmers did to eke out performance back in the day, I wonder if there's some "quick" Euclidean distance algorithm involving bit shifting or pure integer math that would work with that range of values.

Alternatively, I may be reading the value as the wrong data type. Is there some other way to read it that would make more sense? Whatever it is, I'm pretty sure it's big-endian because when you read it that way, the LSB changes when you turn a little and the MSB changes when you turn a lot.

**Clarifications**

- No direction is zero. Instead of the range being 0 <= n < 360, it's 4100 <= n < 8200. 4100 is due south.
- It's definitely 4100-8200, not 4096-8192. Confirmed by setting the character's facing to 4100, running forward, and the X coordinate not changing.
- I don't think there's such a thing as a 16-bit quaternion, and I know what the surrounding bytes are in the client message.
- The game is Dark Age of Camelot. It's entirely possible that 4100-8200 is not a clever algorithmic shortcut but just some boneheaded mistake they were forced to keep for 20 years for backward compatibility. The client/server messages are a bizarre mix of big and little endian values. Sometimes a value is 16 bits in one type of message and 32 in another. The most ridiculous thing is that string fields have a 32-bit Pascal-style length prefix *and* a C-style null terminator... and the length header for the entire message is only 16 bits.

Comment: its probably just because of `sin,cos` **LUT** size also bevare the angles might overlap 360deg range to avoid crossing 0/360 deg problems... also are you sure its 4100 - 8200 instead of 4096 - 8192 that would make more sense as you can use bitmasking instead of modulo (but again it might be the overlap) ...

Comment: Well, if that's not 4100/8200, but 4096 and 8191 (or just below) then it does quite look like a binary encoding. A offset is often used to avoid certain values, like zero. Also, that range looks auspiciously close to 4000 for a circle which would everyone with basic knowledge in geometry (or who has ever played with that switch atop some calculators) remind of [GON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) as there are 400 gon to a full circle, so the number might be in .1 gon. Gon are extreme useful for map drawing or drawing in general as it avoids many problems.

Comment: This is especially true for cases of heading or compass drawing. A compass most often can only take some distinct binary positions, like N/E/S/W which is represented by the top most two bits of a number in gon. Likewise is N/NE/E/SE/... in the top 3 bits, N/NNE/NE/... in the top 4 bits. If this is don in gon, then each client only needs on the top n bits depending on its abilities. Ofc, here's a tiny deviation if it's really deci-gon (0..3999) - but if it's "binary" deci-gon (0..4095) even this would vanish. A further deviation from south as start would also center that out.

Comment: The same is helpful not only for drawing a circular compass but as well a heading (band), as that number, or better the for this clients display useful number of significant  bis can be directly used to index a graphics array or string. A client with text display only and two character display will use the two 3 top bits times 2 to index access the right entry within the string "S SWW NWN NEE SE" - that's maybe 2-5 assembler instructions depending on CPU. (ofc, youngsters can take that as an array indexed by that value divided by a constant and floored, wasting a few thousand instructions :)

Comment: Maybe you can draw a diagram an show us which value each direction has?

Comment: To me it seems clear that a straight south direction is 4100 units, and the angle measure increases in the clockwise direction up to 8200 units = 1 turn.

Comment: @zomega S=4100, W=5125, N=6150, E=7175.

Comment: The low two digits appear to be 'percentage of a full circle starting from south' - 0, 25, 50, 75.

Comment: An odd coincidence, or maybe a clue.  The binary representations of 4100 and 8200 are palindromes (0001000000000100 and 0010000000001000).  If you rotate the hexadecimal representations right cyclically by one digit, you get the decimal!  (1004 → 4100; 2008 → 8200).  

Comment: The reason for the "zero" being 4100 is probably to avoid negative angles. Other than that, I have nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to join the close vote. The question seems clear enough to me; it's about the interpretation of some program code.  But answering it, unless we happen to have a member who recognizes the convention, seems like it's a closer to guesswork.

Comment: @another-dave We have other unanswerable questions: “we don't know the answer” is not an acceptable reason for closure.

Comment: Are we sure that there is a linear correlation between the angle and the output? It might be a vector, e.g an x and y direction and / or speed.

Comment: @MarkWilliams Yes. 5125=W, 6150=N, 7175=E.

Comment: Intersting that if you skip the thousands digit and subtract 100 you get even steps between each point (0=S, 25=W, 50=N, 75=E and 100 back to S). I Suspectthe thousands (and maybe the hundreds) digit(s) have another meaning also.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 is closing it because the game is still active on the internet a valid reason? Unless the client in question is real old, it is probably even illegal to reverse engineer the client to make a new server program.

Comment: @UncleBod Personally, I don't think “it's still active online” is a good close reason; “it's not active online” doesn't make Windows Phone on-topic. Reverse-engineering for interoperability purposes is explicitly legal in many jurisdictions.

Answer (score 7):

**I'm going to go out on a limb with a guess**

You've told us what the numbers are and what the numbers are used for, but you haven't told us how they're used.

It looks like the bits are being used as flags rather than numbers that can be applied to trigonometry. I think this because 4100/8=512.5. Decimals aren't useful, but when you use 512 to test the intercardinal directions, this starts to make sense.

In other words, I think if you take the time to test this, you'll find you can't direct the player in every direction represented by 4100 points of a very precise compass.

The plus signs (+) identify the bits relevant to the comment. That leading zero (a 14-bit binary number) has a purpose, which I'll get to in a moment. The cool reference names come from [compass point naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass).

```
           +++ = cardinal direction SWNE (4 points, start with 4100, inc by 1025)
SS:4100/b0 100 0 000000100
WW:5125/b0 101 0 000000101
NN:6150/b0 110 0 000000110
EE:7175/b0 111 0 000000111

The increment by 1025 is not an error. 4100/4=1025. It happens to work like a charm.

               + = intercardinal direction flag (4 points, add 512 to the cardinal number)
SW:4612/b0 100 1 000000100
NW:5637/b0 101 1 000000101
NE:6150/b0 110 1 000000110
SE:7687/b0 111 1 000000111

And just to add a twist to things, we're not using a reference to the cardinal number
anymore.

                  ++ = half-wind direction flags (8 points, start with 4100+128, inc by 512)
SSW:4228/b0 100 0 01 0000100
WSW:4740/b0 100 1 01 0000100
WNW:5252/b0 101 0 01 0000100
NWW:5764/b0 101 1 01 0000100
NEE:6276/b0 110 0 01 0000100
ENE:6788/b0 110 1 01 0000100
ESE:7300/b0 111 0 01 0000100
SSE:7812/b0 111 1 01 0000100

The first bit of the half-wind flags isn't ignored. The two bits of the half-wind
flags change purpose when the quarter-wind flag is present. In other words, If there's
no quarter-wind flag (0), then the half-wind flags is compass-true (e.g., SSW is SSW).
But if the quarter-wind flag is present (1), the half-wind flags discriminate between
the four options (SbW, SWbS, SWbW, WbS) in proper order.

                      + quarter-wind direction flags (16 points, start with 4100+64, inc by 128)
 SbW:4164/b0 100 0 00 1 000100
SWbS:4292/b0 100 0 01 1 000100
SWbW:4420/b0 100 0 10 1 000100
 WbS:4548/b0 100 0 11 1 000100

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to work out the other 12 combinations and
I'll only provide an example for the rest of the flags.

                       + = quarter-wind half-point flag (32 points)
S½W:4132/b0 100 0 00 0 1 00100

                         + = quarter-wind quarter-point flag (64 points)
S¼W:4116/b0 100 0 00 0 0 1 0100

                           + = quarter-wind eighth-point flag (128 points)
S¼W:4116/b0 100 0 00 0 0 0 1 100
```

Which means the programmers could identify 256 unique directions using, for the most part, single-bit references.

Which brings me to the last three bits, which are always the same as the first three bits (if you ignore the leading zero). My first thought was "this isn't a happy coincidence, it might be a necessary part of the coding." If we compare 4100 and 8200 we find:

```
4100 => #1004 => b01000000000100
                  + = overflow indicator
8200 => #2008 => b10000000001000
```

Conveniently, if the character is turning in a clockwise circle and the game's adding something, like decimal 8 (except for that initial need to increment by 1025, oh dear), then the MSB turns on, indicating the need for a simple right-shift and everything's back to normal.

Except this doesn't work *at all* when turning counter-clockwise (it kinda does, the overflow bit gets turned on, but rather than register shifting now you're resetting the value).

But I think that's a false trail. Why? Because if you examine how the game is using the compass number, I expect you're not going to find math. I expect you're finding flag operations against, at worst, a state machine. A 13-bit register is being used to identify 256 compass directions. Why not just use an 8-bit number? Because you can't change the finer points with only two bit changes. In other words, we're burning a little memory and bandwidth to save what might be a lot of CPU time.

Like I say, it's a guess. As Mr. Spock once said, "We have no evidence, only a theory which happens to fit the facts."

---

***Addendum:** I'm bothered by that idea that the half-wind flag changes meaning if the quarter-wind flag is present conclusion, but I'm convinced all the original programmers are doing is using a state machine with minimal bit changes as direction changes. So my breakdown, while convenient for a human to understand, might have injected some complication that doesn't actually exist.*

Comment: Interesting theory. I'll test it and report back.

Comment: Incidentally, I can't examine how these values are being used since I don't have access to the source of the official server. But we might be able to draw conclusions by trying to set the client to different headings and seeing what the client reports as its heading. I only know it can be set to 4100 exactly and cannot be set to 8200 exactly. (I presume for the same reason 360 isn't a valid conventional heading.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149179/discussion-on-answer-by-jbh-significance-of-compass-heading-values-4100-8200-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Would you mind someone re-doing your monospace formatting using tables and inline markup? It's the sort of thing I'd expect out of a good .txt doc, but also it's about the furthest you can get from semantic HTML using SE markdown, which can cause problems for people.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I have no objection. I admit that I used the PRE blocks because they were convenient. but I recognize that they have their limits - especially on phones. Thank you for asking! That was very courteous.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR: It's most likely noted in 'binary' deci[gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) offset by 4096.

---

### Why?

This is obvious by taking a few simple steps:

1. A *Gon*, also known as [Gradian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian), parts a right angle into 100 equal steps, thus a full circle holds 400 gon.

   Gon is very useful for [Surveying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveying) as it simplifies calculations. Common in Europe, less common in countries based on English heritage (*1).
2. 400 is an odd number for binary machinery (x'190').

   It would be nice to have something more 'straight'
3. 1 0000 0000 0000 or 2^12 or 4096 is a number remarkably close to 4000

   Using 'straight' binary numbers is always a great way to simplify and speed up computing on binary CPUs
4. [Deci as SI prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deci-) means tenth. A circle can thus be expressed as 4000 decigon.
5. Expressing a circle in 4096 steps will thus give all advantages of *gon*_ plus all advantages of 'straight' binary numbers for each of the major directions.
6. Straight binary values also correlate with the quaternary division (4/8/16) of the modern [compass rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass)

   See below for detail.
7. Adding an offset is often done to avoid certain values.

### Direkt Transformation!

By looking at the top bits of that value (0..4095) it's easy to see how all major heading can be devised:

| Bits used | Value | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 00 | S |
|  | 01 | W |
|  | 10 | N |
|  | 11 | E |
| 3 | 000 | S |
|  | 001 | SW |
|  | 010 | W |
|  | 011 | NW |
|  | 100 | N |
|  | 101 | NE |
|  | 110 | E |
|  | 111 | SE |
| 4 | 0000 | S |
|  | 0001 | SSW |
|  | 0010 | SW |
|  | 0011 | ESE |
|  | 0100 | E |

And so on...

### Simple Transformation

##### Textual Client

In case of a textual client a number of bits fitting for the number of directions to be displayed can now be used as an easy index to an array of letters. For example to display

- 4 directions: {"S","W","N","E"}[bits_used]
- 8 directions: {"S","SW","W","NW","N","NO","E","SO"}[bits_used]
- 16 directions: ...

An operation straight out of the data bits without any requirement for further calculation.

##### Graphics Client Using a Compass Rose

Like before a number of bits from the top are used to extract a number, just this time corresponding to the number of different pointer shapes available, so one can be selected.

##### Graphics Client Using a Directional Band

Much like with text, but this time the number of selected bits will be used to index the start of the portion of the band to be shown. For example if the  shown band is 64 pixel wide and the full band is 256 pixel wide, then the top 8 bits are used and offset by minus 32.

### Further Encoding Details

A [comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/significance-of-compass-heading-values-4100-8200-in-an-old-game#comment99629_27839) abut the range being 4100 to 'not reaching' 8200, also shows that the directional value is most likely encoded as 4..4096 with an offset of 4096. A combination that allows handling by simply ignoring any bit above 2^11, eliminating the need of performing any arithmetic functions on client side. Using only the lower 12 bit a range of 4..4096 will result.

Four being the lowest possible value also indicates that the lowest two bits are not used, giving 10 valid bits.

### How to Generate

This of course depends all on how the game internally handles direction.

- If it's done using 360 degree, then

  `(((direction+1)/360)*1024)*4`

  sounds most likely
- If direction handling is already done as 10 bit number, thenit's a straight

  `((direction+1)*4)+4096`

---

Bottom Line: **This all screams a very binary nature made for easy handling without any complex math or costly conversion, well suited for even the lowest powered clients.**

---

Regarding the Clarificaion:

> - No direction is zero. Instead of the range being 0 <= n < 360, it's 4100 <= n < 8200. 4100 is due south.
> - It's definitely 4100-8200, not 4096-8192. Confirmed by setting the character's facing to 4100, running forward, and the X coordinate not changing.

Those two don't match up. Either it's `4100 <= n < 8200` or it's `4100-8200`(including 8200). Especially as the first definition would quite well support the use of 4096 as 4100..8196 - as in 4..4096 with an offset of 4096.

(Also, out of curiosity, isn't DAoC still operating?)

---

*1 - I.e. based on seafaring usage, where [Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)) (360 to a circle) are more useful for position calculation due to being straight dividable by 24.